# How to change a pointer's value by ++ inside a C function?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm not really experienced with pointers in C and I've been given the following code:

```
void backtrack(int *pback1, int *pback2)
{
  if (condition)
      *pback1++;
  else if (another condition)
      *pback2--;
  else if (third condition)
      *pback1++;
  else if (last condition)
      *pback2++;
}

int main()
{
  int b1, b2;
  b1=7, b2=9;
  backtrack(&b1, &b2);
  printf("%d %d", b1, b2);
  return 0;
}
```

The code is printing the result without any changes (7 9).
What should be modified for it to run properly?

Comment: The best solution is probably `*pback1 += 1;` but that kind of defeats the purpose of the exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The postfix `++` and `--` operators have higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than the `*` dereference operator, so `*pback++` increments the pointer `pback` instead of the thing it points to.  You want `(*pback)++`.

Comment: @Lundin: Thanks, updated.  Though for the prefix ones there's no ambiguity, as it's clear what `++*pback` and `*++pback` should do.

Answer (score 2):

you aren't incrementing the value , you are incrementing the pointer , try `(*pback1)++` instead